# How to Disable Apache Haus IT WORKS page in Windows Server 2012

Tags: apache

All I can find on internet is how to remove in linux using /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf. I am using apache on **windows** and I can't find any way to remove it on **windows**.

Answer (score 0):

Remove index.html from htdocs directory. If you installed apache on C:\Apache then index.html location will be  c:\Apache\htdocs\index.html

Comment: Is there a way to change settings without having to delete index.html file?